# Customising a theme

Tags: themes, css

So I'm kinda new to this WordPress infrastructure. Everyone's been telling me about how great WordPress is and how something like 10% of the top sites out there are using it.

So I have a couple of really basic questions about how this all comes together. Maybe they're really obvious, but not so much to me.

1. I found a theme I liked and am using the CSS offered by the Links widget as the main navigation across my site (instead of the CSS in Pages). I therefore created some Pages and am linking to them through Links. However, the site automatically puts links to Pages on the sidebar along with my Links. How do I hide Pages?
2. I created a post for my front page, but I don't like having dates show up? How do I hide?
3. I'd like one CSS style to apply to another class or define a particular object to have another class property. Is there an easy way to do this? Does this require I hack the style sheet?

In general, I have experience with HTML/CSS and some PHP so I know the underlying technologies. However, I would like to know how I can leverage the power of Wordpress while still maintaining the flexibility of a fully powered programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beautiful thing of WordPress (In my opinion) is that you can make almost any website and only have to make a [theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) and or [plugin(s)](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugins).

You can change a theme, delete things, extend etc. Or you can make a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), leaving the original theme intact and overwriting default behavior in a different place.

The rest of WordPress, the core, is there for you making theme or plugin building more easy (framework). You don't have to touch these files.

Now back to your questions :-)

1. Most likely there is a default sidebar with some widgets. In the back-end go to "Appearance" > "Widgets" and there will be a sidebar (like default sidebar or something (depends on theme). When it's empty you can add Widgets and you will see that the default sidebar is "overwritten" with your widgets. If not empty, you can remove the widget called "Pages".
2. In your theme folder you have to look at the template representing your front-page. This can be front-page.php, home.php page.php or index.php. Depending on which one exists (How that works: [Template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy)). Look for a function like `the_date()` or `the_time()`.
3. The CSS is most likely in style.css in the root of your theme folder. Sometimes a theme has a special CSS folder.

That said, you can change anything you want in a theme, but if you want to have the ability to update a theme, you can make a Child theme (See link above).

Comment: and for 1). I cleared out all the widgets, but the posts still show up. So perhaps this theme is no good. for 2) I found index.php. The only function that looks interesting is called get_template_part('inc', 'indexloop' ) ; for 3) I guess I can either change the CSS or just change the class that the links tag points to. I would rather do the latter as the styles.css file is rather complex.

Comment: I see in that theme that they use the WP nav menu in the sidebar (Appearance > Menus). If in theme locations > primary you set the menu you want to show there, you will only see that pages. Or you can edit sidebar.php and remove the `wp_nav_menu()` function.

Comment: Yeah the theme is a bit complex. You can see 2 at content.php

Comment: 3. If you use chrome, you can inspect the element you want to change (rightclick inspect element) and see the css that is used and on which line.

Comment: s was able to hack all the changes. It required a some trial and error, some digging through developer console and a lot of grepping through the code. The sense I get is that Wordpress is just a way to get a big dump of code. Then its up to you to figure out what the code does if you want to customize it and get more "fancy" features. If you don't use any of the blogging capabilities, then huge chunks of Wordpress aren't really used.

Comment: With every framework you use there will be code you won't use. But WP is pretty optimized. For example, you have 1 table with posts (blog), pages, attachments or any type you want. Many code is there for blogging, but also can be used for any other type that's available. Many of the sites I build in WP don't have a blog at all, but still I use 90% of the functionality with WP functions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Wordpressbackend and now go to -> design -> widgets. there you'll find the pages widgets- i hope. Or the theme is hard-coded with the list of pages (no good theme). you could find these code in the sidebar file.
2. i think you must change the template file which generates the date for the front page.
   look for the_time() -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Formatting_Date_and_Time
3. add a class in the themefiles and in the css or http://www.trixya.net/index.php/wordpress/how-to-add-custom-css-file-in-wordpress . i prefer to add a custom css file.

Answer (score -1):

if you know programming language you have a powerful tool at your side. It is more efficient if you use a flexible theme editor and then make the changes, if any required, in the code. In this way you can make things that would take difficult programming by making only a few clicks and then add the suble changes my modifying the code. I use Lubith for example and it offers solutions to some of your problems: it allows you to add/remove certain elements one of them being the meta info, therefore the dates, comments, author etc. Also it allows you to modify the properties to each element of the layout. You simply select them/drag/resize/customize.